# What are hairless spots on men's foreheads called in English?

Tags: word-request

Some people have in their sides of the head, a place without hair (in the right side and left side) like two islands. What is it called in English?

[image]

Comment: receding hairline?

Comment: If it is severe, it is Male Pattern Baldness.  When MPB is just beginning, it is often referred to as a "widow's peak."

Comment: This doesn't apply in this case, but as a sidenote, if it's on the top of your head, it is called a "bald spot."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the degree of hair loss involved.

If the person's hairline just happens to have that shape, but there is no loss of hair, such as in the Gary Cooper image below, it is called a [**widow's peak**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widow%27s_peak).  In this case it is a genetic trait that causes the two halves of a person's hairline to meet at a low point.

[image]

If the hairline is that shape due to hair loss, as I believe it is in your question's image or to a greater degree in the Bruce Willis image below, it is usually called a **receding hairline**, and is the beginning of male pattern baldness.

[image]

There is no particular English term for the patches of bare skin.